# Passing a cupy pointer to a CUDA kernel using ctypes

Tags: python, cuda, ctypes, cupy

I have a CUDA kernel -

```
template <typename T, typename C>
__global__
void cuda_ListArray_num(
  C *tonum,
  const T *fromstarts,
  const T *fromstops
) {
  int64_t block_id = blockIdx.x + blockIdx.y * gridDim.x + gridDim.x * gridDim.y * blockIdx.z;
  int64_t thread_id = block_id * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  int64_t start = fromstarts[thread_id];
  int64_t stop = fromstops[thread_id];
  tonum[thread_id] = (C) (stop - start);
}

ERROR
awkward_ListArray32_num_64(
  int64_t* tonum,
  const int32_t* fromstarts,
  const int32_t* fromstops,
  int64_t length) {

  dim3 blocks_per_grid;
  dim3 threads_per_block;

  if (length > 1024) {
    blocks_per_grid = dim3(ceil((length) / 1024.0), 1, 1);
    threads_per_block = dim3(1024, 1, 1);
  } else {
    blocks_per_grid = dim3(1, 1, 1);
    threads_per_block = dim3(length, 1, 1);
  }

  cuda_ListArray_num<int32_t, int64_t><<<blocks_per_grid, threads_per_block>>>(
    tonum,
    fromstarts,
    fromstops);

  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

  return success();
}
```

I can add this to a `.so` file and load it from Python using `ctypes`. After that, I am trying to use it from Python,

This is the Python equivalent for the `ERROR` struct being returned in the above code block -

```
class Error(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("str", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)),
        ("identity", ctypes.c_int64),
        ("attempt", ctypes.c_int64),
        ("pass_through", ctypes.c_bool),
    ]
```

and here is how I am trying to use it from Python -

```
lib = ctypes.CDLL("cuda-kernels.so")

funcC = getattr(lib, 'awkward_ListArray32_num_64')
funcC.restype = Error

tonum = cupy.array([123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123], dtype=cupy.in64)
tonumx = ctypes.cast(tonum.data.ptr, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int64))
fromstarts = cupy.array([2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1], dtype=cupy.int32)
fromstarts = ctypes.cast(fromstarts.data.ptr, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int32))
fromstops = cupy.array([3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 4, 2, 5, 3, 4, 6, 11], dtype=cupy.int32)
fromstops = ctypes.cast(fromstops.data.ptr, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int32))
length = 3
funcC.argtypes = (ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int64), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int32), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int32), ctypes.c_int64)
ret_pass = funcC(tonumx, fromstarts, fromstops, length)
```

but when I print `tonum` -

```
>>> tonum[:3]
array([0, 0, 0])
```

but the values should be - `[1, 2, 2]` (based on how `cuda_ListArray_num` works)

What could I be doing wrong? I think I might be making a mistake with how I pass the `cupy` pointer to the cuda kernel.

Comment: I think that one of the possible reasons is that the `dtype` of `fromstarts` and `fromstops` cupy array is `int64`. But you are creating `int32` pointers to pass to the library.
You can create the arrays with `cupy.array([..]), dtype=cupy.int32)`

Comment: @emcastillo I tried that (and updated the question with the dtypes) but I got the same, wrong values in `tonum`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the python code to

```
fromstarts = cupy.array([2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1], dtype=cupy.int32)
fromstarts_ctypes = ctypes.cast(fromstarts.data.ptr, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int32))
fromstops = cupy.array([4, 2, 4, 5, 3, 4, 2, 5, 3, 4, 6, 11], dtype=cupy.int32)
fromstops_ctypes = ctypes.cast(fromstops.data.ptr, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int32))
length = 3
funcC.argtypes = (ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int64), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int32), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int32), ctypes.c_int64)
ret_pass = funcC(tonumx, fromstarts_ctypes, fromstops_ctypes, length)
```

The reason is that CuPy arrays are managed with RAII, so when you reassign the `fromstarts` variable to a different object (the ctypes pointer), the actual array gets destroyed and its memory block is returned to CuPy's memory pool. After this, when you create the `fromstops` array, it will use that same memory block, overwriting the contents of the `fromstarts` array as this one is not alive anymore, and sharing both the same pointer.

Then when you call the c code, `fromstarts` and `fromstops` are actually the same pointer. You can verify this with a debugger or just a printf.